# Auto abandon Pull Request after 2 weeks with no updates

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am new in azure devops and scripting. I want to auto abandon azure pull request after 2 weeks with no updates. I am able to list pull request, and do the status update. But looking for a powershell or bash script which can read the list command output, find out the date, and abandon pull request if no update for two week.

```
az repos pr list --repository "myrepo" --status "active"
az repos pr update --id "16729" --status "abandoned"
```

Comment: Hi, you can take a look at the PowerShell script I wrote. I have done a test and it works well on my side. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code can achieve your requirements.

```
$org_name = "<Your Organization Name>"
$project_name = "<Your Project Name>"
$repo_name = "<Your Repo Name>"
$PAT = "<Your Personal Access Token>"

$headers_prs = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers_prs.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+$PAT)

$prs_url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+$org_name+"/"+$project_name+"/_apis/git/repositories/"+$repo_name+"/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"
$response_prs = Invoke-RestMethod $prs_url -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers_prs
$response_prs | ConvertTo-Json

$response_prs.value | foreach {
    $pr_id = $_.pullRequestId
    # Write-Host $pr_id
    $create_date = $_.creationDate
    # Write-Host $create_date # Get all of the PRs' create dates
    ###
    $headers_pr = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers_pr.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+$PAT)
    $headers_pr.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    
    $body_pr = "{
    `n    `"contributionIds`": [
    `n        `"ms.vss-code-web.pullrequests-artifact-stats-data-provider`"
    `n    ],
    `n    `"dataProviderContext`": {
    `n        `"properties`": {
    `n            `"artifactIds`": [
    `n                {
    `n                    `"artifactId`": `"vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6%2F044a82e2-9d12-43b2-801c-d33ac6812173%2F"+$pr_id+"`",
    `n                    `"discussionArtifactId`": `"vstfs:///CodeReview/ReviewId/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6%2F"+$pr_id+"`"
    `n                }
    `n            ],
    `n            `"sourcePage`": {
    `n                `"url`": `"https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_git/<Repo Name>/pullrequests?_a=mine`",
    `n                `"routeId`": `"ms.vss-code-web.lwp-prs-route`",
    `n                `"routeValues`": {
    `n                    `"project`": `"<Project Name>`",
    `n                    `"GitRepositoryName`": `"<Repo Name>`",
    `n                    `"vctype`": `"git`",
    `n                    `"controller`": `"ContributedPage`",
    `n                    `"action`": `"Execute`",
    `n                    `"serviceHost`": `"b1cc953d-b564-4eec-a222-84393e4406b1 (<some personal information>)`"
    `n                }
    `n            }
    `n        }
    `n    }
    `n}"

    $pr_url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+$org_name+"/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery/project/"+$project_name+"?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
    $response_pr = Invoke-RestMethod $pr_url -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers_pr -Body $body_pr
    $response_pr | ConvertTo-Json

    $last_updated_time_stamp = $response_pr.dataProviders.'ms.vss-code-web.pullrequests-artifact-stats-data-provider'.'TFS.VersionControl.PullRequestListArtifactStatsProvider.artifactStats'.lastUpdatedDate
    if($last_updated_time_stamp -ne $null){
        Write-Host 'last update time stamp is not null.'
        Write-Host $last_updated_time_stamp
        $last_updated_time = Get-Date -Date $last_updated_time_stamp
        $now_time = Get-Date
        Write-Host $now_time
        $diff_time = $now_time - $last_updated_time
        Write-Host $diff_time.TotalSeconds
        #if the diff is longer than two weeks
        if ($diff_time.TotalSeconds -gt 60*60*24*14) {
            Write-Host "The difference is greater than two weeks"
            #Abandon the PR here.
            #==========================================================
            $headers_abpr = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
            $headers_abpr.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+$PAT)
            $headers_abpr.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
            
            $body_abpr = "{
            `n    `"status`":`"abandoned`"
            `n}"
            $abpr_url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+$org_name+"/"+$project_name+"/_apis/git/repositories/"+$repo_name+"/pullrequests/"+$pr_id+"?api-version=6.0"
            $response_abpr = Invoke-RestMethod $abpr_url -Method 'PATCH' -Headers $headers_abpr -Body $body_abpr
            $response_abpr | ConvertTo-Json
            Write-Host 'Abandoned successfully.'
            #==========================================================
        } else {
            Write-Host "The difference is less than two weeks"
        }
    }elseif ($last_updated_time_stamp -eq $null) {
        Write-Host 'last update time stamp is null.'
        Write-Host $last_updated_time_stamp
        $last_updated_time = Get-Date -Date $create_date
        $now_time = Get-Date
        $diff_time = $now_time - $last_updated_time
        Write-Host $diff_time.TotalSeconds
        if ($diff_time.TotalSeconds -gt 60*60*24*14) {
            Write-Host "The difference is greater than two weeks"
            #Abandon the PR here.
            #==========================================================
            $headers_abpr = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
            $headers_abpr.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+$PAT)
            $headers_abpr.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
            
            $body_abpr = "{
            `n    `"status`":`"abandoned`"
            `n}"
            $abpr_url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+$org_name+"/"+$project_name+"/_apis/git/repositories/"+$repo_name+"/pullrequests/"+$pr_id+"?api-version=6.0"
            $response_abpr = Invoke-RestMethod $abpr_url -Method 'PATCH' -Headers $headers_abpr -Body $body_abpr
            $response_abpr | ConvertTo-Json
            Write-Host 'Abandoned successfully.'
            #==========================================================
        } else {
            Write-Host "The difference is less than two weeks"
        }
    }
    ###
}
```

The official REST API documents don't have such data 'last update time' of Pull requests. The above code is based on network traffic interception and analysis. The above code has been tested by me and works very well on my side.

There may be a lot of code, I will share with you the ideas of how I code those here. These will help you understand the above code.

**Steps:**

***1, get all of the pull requests information, especially the 'id'.***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

ID and Name in this REST API is equivalent.

***2, Go to the pull request page and analyze.***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please notice that if you only create pull request but do nothing, last updated time in this  place will be 'null', you need to use pull request 'creation time' in this situation.

***3, calculate the difference between the last update time and the now time.***

```
$ago = Get-Date -Date "<Time String>"
$now = Get-Date

$diff = $now - $ago
Write-Host $diff.TotalSeconds
#if the diff is longer than two weeks
if ($diff.TotalSeconds -gt 60*60*24*14) {
    Write-Host "The difference is greater than two weeks"
} else {
    Write-Host "The difference is less than two weeks"
}
```

**The most important is the second step, because only this place has the relevant information of last updated time of pull request.**

As long as you have ideas about how to deal with the problem, you can write code in any language you can to achieve your requirements.

Comment: I have updated the variables in starting. Also updated url variables at line 37, `"url`": `"https://dev.azure.com/$org_name/$project_name/_git/$repo_name/pullrequests?_a=mine`",


getting below error
last update time stamp is null.
15 |  $response_prs.value | foreach {
     |                        ~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting
     | "Date": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."

Comment: resolved that issue by
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $PAT)))
$headers_prs= @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) }

Error
111 |  … onse_abpr = Invoke-RestMethod $abpr_url -Method 'PATCH' -Headers $hea …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The request
     | indicated a Content-Type of \"\" for method type \"PATCH\"
     | which is not supported. Valid content types for this method
     | are: application/json,

Answer (score 0):

@Bowman Zhu-MSFT Helped me to resolve this issue, Thanks for guidance, and as he said "As long as you have ideas about how to deal with the problem, you can write code in any language you can to achieve your requirements. "I only tweaked some of the code, Like for header I am using different code, using az cli for abandon PR.

```
    - task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
            $org_name = "XXX"
            $project_name = "XXXX"
            $repo_name = "XXX"
            $PAT = $env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT
            
            $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $PAT)))
            $headers_prs = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) }
            
            $prs_url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+$org_name+"/"+$project_name+"/_apis/git/repositories/"+$repo_name+"/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"
            $response_prs = Invoke-RestMethod $prs_url -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers_prs
            
            $response_prs.value | foreach {
                Write-Host 'repository name'  $repo_name
                $pr_id = $_.pullRequestId
                Write-Host 'pr id ='  $pr_id
                $create_date = $_.creationDate 
                Write-Host 'pr create date = '   $create_date # Get all of the PRs' create dates
                $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $PAT)))
                $headers_pr = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) }
            
            
                $pr1_url = "https://dev.azure.com/$org_name/$project_name/_apis/git/repositories/$repo_name/pullRequests/$pr_id/threads?api-version=6.0"
                $response_pr1 = Invoke-RestMethod $pr1_url -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers_pr
                $count = $response_pr1.value.count
                $last_updated_time_stamp  = $response_pr1.value[$count-1].lastUpdatedDate   
              
                
                if($last_updated_time_stamp -ne $null){
                    Write-Host 'last update time stamp is not null.'
                    #Write-Host $last_updated_time_stamp
                    $last_updated_time = Get-Date -Date $last_updated_time_stamp
                    Write-Host 'last_updated_time = ' $last_updated_time
                    $now_time = Get-Date
                    Write-Host 'current time = ' $now_time
                    $diff_time = $now_time - $last_updated_time
                    Write-Host 'time difference in seconds = ' $diff_time.TotalSeconds
                    #if the diff is longer than four weeks
                    if ($diff_time.TotalSeconds -gt 60*60*24*30) {
                        Write-Host "The difference is greater than four weeks"
                        #Abandon the PR here.
                        #==========================================================
                        az devops configure --defaults organization=$org_name
                        az repos pr update --id $pr_id --status "abandoned" 
                        Write-Host 'Abandoned successfully.'
                        #==========================================================
                    } else {
                        Write-Host "The difference is less than four weeks"
                    }
                }elseif ($last_updated_time_stamp -eq $null) {
                    #Write-Host $last_updated_time_stamp
                    $last_updated_time = Get-Date -Date $create_date
                    Write-Host 'last_updated_time = ' $last_updated_time
                    $now_time = Get-Date
                    Write-Host 'current time = ' $now_time
                    $diff_time = $now_time - $last_updated_time
                    Write-Host 'time difference in seconds = ' $diff_time.TotalSeconds
                    #if the diff is longer than four weeks
                    if ($diff_time.TotalSeconds -gt 60*60*24*30) {
                        Write-Host "The difference is greater than four weeks"
                        #Abandon the PR here.
                        #==========================================================
                        az devops configure --defaults organization=$org_name
                        az repos pr update --id $pr_id --status "abandoned"    
                        Write-Host 'Abandoned successfully.' 
                         #==========================================================          
                    } else {
                        Write-Host "The difference is less than four weeks"
                    }
                }
                ###
            }
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(PAT_svc_azuresync)
```